# How to configure FUEL SDK environment variables for Exact Target API?

Tags: python-2.7, api, soap, salesforce, exacttarget

This is a very basic question and first time I am doing something like this professionally, but I am trying to build applications using the Exact Target API from Salesforce using the FUEL SDK. I would like to use the SOAP API functionality within FUEL.

I have gotten directions from the git repostory found here (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python)

My question is in the directions on Git it says to copy the

> "config.python.template" that contain the environment variables to
>   either "config.python" or "~/.fuelsdk/",

how do I find these locations?

I am using anaconda python and have looked in the python path, but I can not find either of those files.

Could someone please help me find the files or direct me where to put in the environment variables?

So far I added the environment variables directly in the code provided on the git site, but get the error

> "Exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret)
>   provided: {u'errorcode': 10005, u'message': u'clientId is required',
>   u'documentation': u''}"

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Any luck with this? Having the same issue

Comment: @Data_Kid unfortunately not, left the company I was working on this for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file in question is

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/blob/master/FuelSDK/config.python.template

But once You set your clientId/secreID You need to rename it into `config.python`

That's it.